# .net core cli - build on Linux and Windows - Issues with string comparison and accents

Tags: linux, encoding, .net-core

I switched my CI tool to call `dotnet build` on Linux whereas I was previoulsy doing it on Windows. Then I suddenly had a bug in my app.

I am comparing a variable read from database to a string litteral (directly in the code) returned from a method. The string litteral has French accents. So does the value stored in the db (SQL Server).

However, the line that does the string comparison returns true when built on Windows but false when built from Linux.

How come?

UPDATE

Here the exception message that showed me the issue:

```
throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(modeDePaiement), modeDePaiement, "Mode de paiement non supporté");
```

When displaying the error, `modeDePaiement` was equal to "prélèvement" both when built from Windows or Linux.

However, the value it is compared against AS WELL AS the word "supporté" in the error message weren't displayed equally: when built from Linux the "é" is replaced with some symbol whereas it is correctly displayed when built from Windows.

It seems that strings, in code, are not encoded the same way when built from Linux or Windows.

Comment: Did you try to print the value to the console output or file or anywhere? Do you use a specific CultureInfo or the default current culture?

Comment: Possibly related: [Unicode normalization](http://unicode.org/reports/tr15/). Please [edit] the question and provide the symbol(s) noticed in _when built from Linux the "é" is replaced with **some symbol**_. Simply copy garbled "`prélèvement`" and "`supporté`" words…

Comment: I can't edit right now as I have to reproduce the problem first. Indeed, as it was an issue in production, I rewrote the method entierly differently to pass through the problem. But I will try to reproduce it as a sample later to review the problem as I'm interested in understanding the reason of it.